# Undefined attributes in Parse

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to handle my backend and I'm encountering issues grabbing data from my Parse objects. I've seen many questions similar to this, but none with a straightforward answer.

My `User` objects have a field called `groupsArray` which is an array that contains `Group` objects. Each `Group` object then contains a field called `groupName`, which is simply the name of that particular group object.

Here is my trouble. I'm grabbing the current user via

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
```

then I grab the groupsArray and the groupNames via

```
var groupsArray = user.get("groupsArray");
var groupName = groupsArray[i].get("groupName");
```

Initially this works after I add a group, *however*, my problem comes after I refresh my browser. After refreshing my browser, all my `groupName` fields are `undefined`. When I try and grab their `id`, it works, but all the personal fields that I created for that object is undefined. When I go to my applications dashboard on parse.com, I see all the objects with their groupNames. Anyone know what's going on?

More detailed code:

Inside groups.js, which calls modelGroups.js:

```
$('#tester').on('click', function() {
    populateSidebar();
});
```

Inside modelGroups.js:

```
function populateSidebar(){
    var groupsArray = Parse.User.current().get("groupsArray");
    for (var i=0; i<groupsArray.length; i++) {
        var groupName = groupsArray[i].get("groupName");
        console.log(groupName); // ALL of these are undefined after a browser refresh
    }
}
```

And yes, even after refreshing the browser, Parse.User.current() is fetching the correct user, user.id, and username

Comment: can you provide full code,  fiddle , or live example please?

Comment: just added more code

Comment: please console log groupsArray just after parsing user , and tell me if it gets logged properely.

Comment: @ProllyGeek yes the current user is being logged correctly.

Comment: @ProllyGeek woops you asked for groupsArray. groupsArray is also being logged correctly, with the correct size as well. Some fields, after refreshing, however, get modified. For example, "hasData" becomes false after a browser refresh

Comment: It seems that the group data needs to be fetched from database again after refresh to me. Never happened on iOS since I enabled local datastore for me.

Comment: @Flying_Banana this worked! I called a fetch on my objects before trying to retrieve data. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help! I'll just copy and paste that to an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the group data needs to be fetched from database again after refresh to me. Never happened on iOS since I enabled local datastore for me.